# How to read contents of a CSV file inside zip file using spark (python)

Tags: python, apache-hadoop, apache-spark

I have multiple zip files containing two types of files(A.csv & B.csv)

/data/jan.zip --> contains A.csv & B.csv
/data/feb.zip --> contains A.csv & B.csv

I want to read the contents of all the A.csv files inside all the zip files using pyspark.

```
 textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://<HDFS loc>/data/*.zip")
```

Can someone tell me how to get the contents of A.csv files into an RDD?

Comment: this is a programming or coding related question, and suits Stackoverflow than Data Science. I think this should be moved to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the package [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) is loaded; e.g., by invoking the `spark-shell` with the flag `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0`. After that you can use `sc.textFile` as you did, or `sqlContext.read.format("csv").load`. You might need to use `csv.gz` instead of just `zip`; I don't know, I haven't tried.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://districtdatalabs.silvrback.com/getting-started-with-spark-in-python) website would help you out. In the topic called **Writing a Spark Application**, they've described reading file contents from a zip folder. Cheers!